# Inverse Rotation and Translation for Pinhole Projection

Tags: python, camera, projection, robotics, perspectivecamera

So, I feel really dumb to try to solve this problem for so long. I really need help.

I am trying to project the camera pixel coordinate to the world coordinate using Pinhole perspective projection. But somehow the rays I generate has weird rotation (direction). So the function is:

```
def pixel_coords_to_world_coords_ray(pixel_coords, camera_matrix, distortion_coeffs, R_world_to_camera, t_world_to_camera, plane_normal_world, plane_distance_world):
    
    pixel_coords_undistorted, newcameramtx = undistort_contour_pixel(pixel_coords, camera_matrix, distortion_coeffs)
    pixel_coords_undistorted = np.squeeze(pixel_coords_undistorted, axis=1)
    pixel_coords_homogeneous = np.hstack((pixel_coords_undistorted, np.ones((len(pixel_coords_undistorted), 1))))
    
    # Invert the camera matrix to get pixel to ray conversion matrix
    camera_matrix_inv = np.linalg.inv(newcameramtx)
    
    # Compute the light ray direction in the camera frame.
    ray_directions_camera = (camera_matrix_inv @ pixel_coords_homogeneous.T)[:3, :]

    # Transform the light ray direction to the world frame
    R_camera_to_world = R_world_to_camera.T
    t_camera_to_world = -R_camera_to_world @ t_world_to_camera
    ray_directions_world = R_camera_to_world @ ray_directions_camera
    
    # Normalize the rays to have unit length
    ray_directions_world /= np.linalg.norm(ray_directions_world, axis=0)
    
    # Compute the intersection between the light rays and the plane
    ray_origin_world = t_camera_to_world.reshape(3)
    world_coords = []
    for ray_direction_world in ray_directions_world.T:
        intersection = ray_plane_intersection(ray_origin_world, ray_direction_world, plane_normal_world, plane_distance_world)
        if intersection is not None:
            world_coords.append(intersection)
    world_coords = np.array(world_coords)

    return world_coords
```

- So I've tried to debug it by setting the input pixel to be (w/2, h/2). It results to the expected value of ray_directions_camera = near [0,0,1]

But somehow the rotation I get in the ray's direction in world frame is wrong.

- I also plot the result, the transformation and rotation of the camera. So the translation and rotation must be right.

[image]

the red line pointing downward at the middle is the resulting ray for the pixel (w/2, h/2)

Am I missing something here? It's been a week I am trying to solve this with many different method. I really need to finish this. Thank you all.